# Selenium RC - grid hub is not listening

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-grid, tools.jar

I'm new to selenium.
I am running an existing selenium RC code.
When i try to launch the hub I got the following error

Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\tools.jar
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed

So I downloaded JDK files. Then I changed the system variables
Now it is pointing to

```
C:\>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11

C:\>echo %PATH%
c:\ruby\bin;C:\ant\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C
:\Program Files\Windows Imaging\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLS
hared\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_05\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11

C:\>echo %ANT_HOME%
C:\ant\bin\ant.bat
```

I ran the following bat file to launch the hub  - launch hub.bat

```
title Hub
cd C:\selenium\Grid\selenium-grid-1.0.4
c:\ant\bin\ant launch-hub
```

**OUTPUT**

```
C:\selenium\Grid\selenium-grid-1.0.4>c:\ant\bin\ant launch-hub
Buildfile: build.xml

launch-hub:
     [java] jan 16, 2013 2:45:25 PM com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.hub.HubRegist
ry gridConfiguration
     [java] INFO: Loaded grid configuration:
     [java] ---
     [java] hub:
     [java]   environments:
     [java]     -
     [java]       browser: "*firefox"
     [java]       name: Firefox on Windows
     [java]     -
     [java]       browser: "*firefox"
     [java]       name: Firefox on OS X
     [java]     -
     [java]       browser: "*firefox"
     [java]       name: Firefox on Linux
     [java]     -
     [java]       browser: "*iehta"
     [java]       name: IE on Windows
     [java]     -
     [java]       browser: "*safari"
     [java]       name: Safari on OS X
     [java]     -
     [java]       browser: "*firefox"
     [java]       name: "*firefox"
     [java]     -
     [java]       browser: "*firefox2"
     [java]       name: "*firefox2"
     [java]     -
     [java]       browser: "*firefox3"
     [java]       name: "*firefox3"
     [java]     -
     [java]       browser: "*chrome"
     [java]       name: "*chrome"
     [java]     -
     [java]       browser: "*iexplore"
     [java]       name: "*iexplore"
     [java]     -
     [java]       browser: "*iehta"
     [java]       name: "*iehta"
     [java]     -
     [java]       browser: "*safari"
     [java]       name: "*safari"
     [java]     -
     [java]       browser: "*opera"
     [java]       name: "*opera"
     [java]     -
     [java]       browser: "*googlechrome"
     [java]       name: "*googlechrome"
     [java]     -
     [java]       browser: "*firefoxproxy"
     [java]       name: "*firefoxproxy"
     [java]     -
     [java]       browser: "*pifirefox"
     [java]       name: "*pifirefox"
     [java]     -
     [java]       browser: "*iexploreproxy"
     [java]       name: "*iexploreproxy"
     [java]     -
     [java]       browser: "*piiexplore"
     [java]       name: "*piiexplore"
     [java]     -
     [java]       browser: "*safariproxy"
     [java]       name: "*safariproxy"
     [java]
     [java] 2013-01-16 14:45:25.161::INFO:  Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.lo
g.StdErrLog
     [java] 2013-01-16 14:45:25.224::INFO:  jetty-6.0.x
     [java] 2013-01-16 14:45:25.364::WARN:  failed SocketConnector @ 0.0.0.0:444
4
     [java] java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
     [java]     at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl
.java:376)
     [java]     at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.bind(TwoStacksPlainSocketIm
pl.java:101)
     [java]     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:175)
     [java]     at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
     [java]     at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
     [java]     at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.newServerSocket(SocketC
onnector.java:78)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.open(SocketConnector.ja
va:72)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector
.java:251)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.doStart(SocketConnector
.java:145)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCyc
le.java:40)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:239)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCyc
le.java:40)
     [java]     at com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.hub.HubServer.main(HubServer.j
ava:39)
     [java] 2013-01-16 14:45:25.364::WARN:  failed Server@d38c3d
     [java] java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
     [java]     at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl
.java:376)
     [java]     at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.bind(TwoStacksPlainSocketIm
pl.java:101)
     [java]     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:175)
     [java]     at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
     [java]     at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
     [java]     at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.newServerSocket(SocketC
onnector.java:78)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.open(SocketConnector.ja
va:72)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector
.java:251)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.doStart(SocketConnector
.java:145)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCyc
le.java:40)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:239)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCyc
le.java:40)
     [java]     at com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.hub.HubServer.main(HubServer.j
ava:39)
     [java] Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already i
n use: JVM_Bind
     [java]     at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl
.java:376)
     [java]     at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.bind(TwoStacksPlainSocketIm
pl.java:101)
     [java]     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:175)
     [java]     at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
     [java]     at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
     [java]     at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.newServerSocket(SocketC
onnector.java:78)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.open(SocketConnector.ja
va:72)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector
.java:251)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.doStart(SocketConnector
.java:145)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCyc
le.java:40)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:239)
     [java]     at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCyc
le.java:40)
     [java]     at com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.hub.HubServer.main(HubServer.j
ava:39)
```

My training document says I should 
 • Wait to see the ‘started Socket Connector’ statement and ‘44’;

But I didn't get it.
I think it is because of failed SocketConnector.
Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines tells you that the port 4444 is already opened by another process

```
 [java] 2013-01-16 14:45:25.364::WARN:  failed SocketConnector @ 0.0.0.0:4444
 [java] java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
```

You should check what this process could be and shut it, or modify your build.xml to change the port on which the hub is to start

Use `netstat -an` on Windows

NOTE : If you've run your ant file multiple times, the process that opened the 4444 port is maybe the same that you're trying to launch, which has no yet be terminated.

Comment: Thanks :) it worked now, my hub is listening. I ran rake hub:stop to close the hub